# How to remove or respawn robots during the simulation?

Tags: ros, robot, respawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

I am a new ros user. Currently, I am implementing an algorithm by using Ros platform with Gazebo simulator. I will use a group of robot (at least 10 hector quadrotors) for the simulations. And under some certains conditions, the robot need to be removed or respawned during the simulation.

I use .cpp file as a rosnode to run the controllers (algorithm) for all robots. Does anyone know how to realize this dynamic removal or respawn through .cpp file? or .launch file?

Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259700/how-to-remove-or-respawn-robots-during-the-simulation?/) by [jasonwang538@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/30092/jasonwang538@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please don't ask duplicate questions. Your other version of this has an answer.

http://answers.ros.org/question/259741/how-to-remove-and-respawn-robot/

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0